# C# - Displaying character count without counting spaces?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

This program counts and displays the number of words and the number of characters as the user is typing. The "word counter" is working fine, but I cannot figure out how to count the characters without counting the spaces in between.

```
private void userTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userInput = userTextBox.Text;
    userInput = userInput.Trim();
    string[] wordCount = userInput.Split(null);

    //Here is my error
    string[] charCount = wordCount.Length;

    wordCountOutput.Text = wordCount.Length.ToString();
    charCountOutput.Text = charCount.Length.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're name is "Learning2Code" I thought I'd give you an answer that fixes your original attempt using the least advanced technique:

```
private void userTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userInput = userTextBox.Text;
    userInput = userInput.Trim();
    string[] wordCount = userInput.Split(null);

    int charCount = 0;
    foreach (var word in wordCount)
        charCount += word.Length;

    wordCountOutput.Text = wordCount.Length.ToString();
    charCountOutput.Text = charCount.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use LINQ to count characters without white-spaces:

```
int charCount = userInput.Count(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
```

However, your code suggests that you just don't know how to count the words, so

replace

```
string[] charCount = wordCount.Length;
```

with

```
int words = wordCount.Length;
```

Comment: The first line of code works perfectly. I just had to remove ".Lenghth" from the bottom. Thanks Tim

Answer (score 2):

You have each word already, so count the characters in each word and sum the total:

```
var charCount = words.Sum(w => w.Length);
```

Note: you stored the word array as 'wordCount' - I renamed it to just 'words' in the above snippet to be semantically correct. ie:

```
string[] words = userInput.Split(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace all the spaces (and new lines characters) with Regex:

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, "[\s\n]", "");
```

Comment: I hardly think a regex is appropriate for this task!

Comment: More to the point, why do you think so! Hint: don't introduce complexity. As a programmer, your job is to reduce complexity!

Comment: I am do, because I've written this one (but not another), and you actually giving (at least, trying to) some your point. Generally, I like the answer Tyson provided, for sure. But it depends what is the text entered, what characters would need to be counted.

Comment: Oh I see! It's the way to it because you've done it this way before. lol! have you not heard this phrase "You have solved a problem with a regex. Now you have two problems"

Comment: Aha. So, your point is not to use regular expressions in development at all? Interesting. Never heard any such "philosophy" from guys with such a big rating. ;)

Comment: That's not what I said, and I think you know it.

Answer (score 0):

There is one space less than the number of words (for example `"once upon a time"` contains four words and three spaces), so you can calculate the number of spaces. Then just subtract the number of spaces from the length of the input string:

```
int charCount = userInput.Length - (wordCount.Length - 1);
```

As that is an integer and not a string array, don't use `Length` when you output the result:

```
charCountOutput.Text = charCount.ToString();
```